# Why is my spoiler formatting not working?

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

Why is my spoiler formatting not working? 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271521/310756

I've fiddled around with it and I cannot get my comments to be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoiler blocks can't be followed immediately by regular text. I guess you mistakenly added a line break in between.

Your code looked like this:

```
>! a
b
>! c
>! d
```

> ! a
>   b
>   ! c
>   ! d

While it should be:

```
>! a
>! b
>! c
>! d
```

> a
>  b
>  c
>  d

Comment: Thanks Patrick, will accept this shortly, **BUT** asking this question led me to find the **ANSWER** to the **SECRET HAT** *(I seriously need a life, I'm way too excited about this)* LOL